# Flutter - How to pause application while shared preferences is loading?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use method, that I call from InitState() where load SP with await.
But Widget is constructing before SP is loaded and have got empty SP values.

```
void getSP() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _todoItems = prefs.getStringList("key") ?? _todoItems;
  }
```

Full code: https://pastebin.com/EnxfKgPH

Answer (score 9, accepted):

there are many options, one i like is to use boolean variable like this

```dart
bool isLoaded = false;
    
@override
void initState() {
  getSP();
  super.initState();
}
    
void getSP() async {
  var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  _todoItems = prefs.getStringList("key") ?? _todoItems;
  setState(() => isLoaded = true);
}
```

then check it to determine if build tree should load or not, like this..

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return !isLoaded ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Scaffold(...);
}
```

Comment: Oh my God! Why didn't I see this answer 3 excruciating days ago!?! I haven't actually tried this yet, but I'm certain it's the answer to my current dilemma. Thank you.